# ApplicationSignInManager could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am running into the following issue: `ApplicationSignInManager is not being found (Missing Assembly or reference)`

I am looking into building something like this

Link: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-MVC-5-Security-And-44cbdb97#content

Before I start building I wanted to test the code. But running the application result to the following error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'ApplicationSignInManager'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)   30  Active

```
sing System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;
using IntranetVKR.Models;

namespace IntranetVKR
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864 
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request 
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please see the ApplicationSignInManager class is defined or not in IdentityConfig.cs